# Update EnvironmentObject value in ViewModel and then reflect the update in a View

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an environment object with the property `auth` in my root `ContentView`:

```
class User: ObservableObject {
    @Published var auth = false
}
```

My goal is to update `auth` to `true` inside of a function in my `AuthViewModel`:

```
class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    
    var user: User = User() 

    
    func verifyCode(phoneNumber: String, secret: String) {
        
                self.user.auth = true
                
        }.task.resume()
        
    }
}
```

And then in my `AuthView`, I want to print the change when the function `verifyCode` is called:

```
 @EnvironmentObject var user: User

 var body: some View {
        
        print("AUTH SETTINGS -------->",user.auth)
        
        
        return VStack() { ........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your class `User` doesn´t contain any further logic it would be best to declare it as `struct` and either let it live inside your `AuthViewModel` ***or*** in the View as a `@State` var. You should have only one source of truth for your data.

As for the print question:

```
let _ = print(....)
```

should work.